# How can I use valgrind with Python code to detect race condition?

Tags: python, valgrind

I have Python code with race condition.

```
import threading
class Counter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
    def incr(self):
        self.x += 1
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.x)

x = Counter()

class T(threading.Thread):
  def run(self):
        for i in range(100000):
            x.incr()

t1 = T()
t2 = T()
t1.start()
t2.start()
t1.join()
t2.join()
print(x)
```

And I trying to use valgrind to detect it.

```
valgrind --tool=helgrind --suppressions=valgrind-python.supp \python -E -tt ./1.py
0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 9 from 9)
```

Can I use valgrind to detect race condition in Python code?

Answer (score 0):

The standard implementation of Python uses a global interpreter lock to ensure that only one thread at a time can be executing Python bytecode.

So from valgrind's perspective, only one thread is running.